# IRC client with ability to verify server's self-signed cert fingerprint

Tags: certificates, man-in-the-middle, fingerprint, certificate-pinning, self-signed

I'm playing around with UnrealIRCd on CentOS. Just went through the config and compiling and got the ircd up and running.

When I go to connect to it via HexChat I can only get through by checking the box on HexChat that allows self-signed certs.

This is bad over the Internet unless there is a way for me to crosscheck the cert's fingerprint on HexChat before connecting.

I have the fingerprint for the cert from when UnrealIRCd generated it.

I'm looking for ways to secure my IRC connection without the use of a CA

Comment: I don't know about HexChat, but I know IRSSI now has this ability.

Comment: Yes, Irssi is nice. Any alternatives? Ones with GUI

Comment: Unfortunately product recommendations are off-topic here (not that I'm trying to hide the answer from you, I don't know).